# Working with multi-arrays and avoid repeating values in a table

Tags: php, arrays

I am working on a Symfony CRM and part of the CRM requires a list of values based on property units and four different websites linked to the CRM.

My table is set up as follows:

```
| site_id | rate_type | unit_id | value |
-----------------------------------------
|    1    |     1     |    1    |  0.9  |
|    2    |     1     |    1    |  1.1  |
|    3    |     1     |    1    |  1.0  |
|    4    |     1     |    1    |  0.8  |
-----------------------------------------
```

Basically there is a different value (the value here is linked to a rate for staying at the property unit) for each unit and each rate type, but it's different based on the site ID (as you can see from the different values in the table).

I'd like it to display on screen like this:

```
Units                  Site 1       Site 2      Site 3      Site 4
-------------------------------------------------------------------
RATE TYPE NAME HERE
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Unit Name 1              0.9          1.1        1.0         0.8
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So each value is on the SAME line for each website, and in my PHP I am doing this:

```
$html = "";
foreach($multipliers as $ratetype) {
    $html .= '<tr style="background:#EEEEEE;font-weight:700">
        <td colspan="5">' . $ratetype->getRateType()->getDisplayName() . '</td>
    </tr>';
    foreach($multipliers as $multi) {
        $html .= '<tr>
            <td>' . $multi->getUnitId()->getUnitName() . '</td>';
        foreach($multipliers as $value) {
            $html .= '<td class="text-center">' . $value->getValue() . '</td>';
        }
        $html .= '</tr>';
    }
}
```

But this gives me this on screen:

```
Units                  Site 1       Site 2      Site 3      Site 4
-------------------------------------------------------------------
RATE TYPE NAME HERE
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Unit Name 1              0.9          1.1        1.0         0.8
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Unit Name 1              0.9          1.1        1.0         0.8
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Unit Name 1              0.9          1.1        1.0         0.8
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Unit Name 1              0.9          1.1        1.0         0.8
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Because it's clearly looping through each entry in the database rather than just showing each record in the one line. Arrays have never been my strong point so looking for help trying to get this data to display the way I need it!

Comment: Why do you keep using `$multipliers` in each `foreach`? can you include the code that assigns the values for those variables?

Comment: I actually changed the table structure in the end, since there is only ever 4 websites I added each one as a column so it's only one entry per row. Incidentally, I thought I had deleted this question lol